# Deploy a stack in docker using Variable substitution

Tags: docker, variables, environment-variables

I am trying to deploy a stack in docker using variable substitution, but when I run  `docker stack deploy --compose-file email.yaml email`, I get **invalid reference format** error. Here it is my email.yaml:

```
version: '3' 
services:   
  emailservice:
    image: 'email:${VERSION}'
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 300 MB
      update_config:
        delay: 12s
    ports:
     - "8000:80"
```

I have tried `email:${VERSION}` and `"email:${VERSION}"`, but it does not work either.

On the other hand, I have read that in docker stack deploy, I cannot use .env file to pass variables. How should I pass them??

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**docker stack deploy** does not process .env file by default. It is a docker-compose feature. You can preprocess it in one line.

```
docker stack deploy -c <(docker-compose config) stack-name-here
```

Ref: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133#issuecomment-442912378

Answer (score 3):

Docker Compose automatically loads `.env` file, but `docker stack deploy` does not (see the note in [Variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) section of the Compose file reference).

You can workaround that by using `env VAR=VALUE` in the same line as `docker stack deploy`:

```
$ env VERSION=1.2 docker stack deploy -c email.yaml email
```

The syntax you used is correct, but because of the missing substitution is causing the error you see.

Alternatively, you could force the variable to be defined by using `${VERSION:?}` syntax requirement, which will stop the deployment and display an error easy to relate to the missing variable:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c email.yaml email
invalid interpolation format for services.emailservice.image: "required variable VERSION is missing a value: ". You may need to escape any $ with another $.
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/939) opened for this.
I had the same problem, and the best workaround I could find came from [this comment](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/939#issuecomment-493920237).

The suggested workaround uses `docker-compose config` to generate the docker-compose.yml output (with variables substitution):

```
docker-compose config | docker stack deploy --compose-file - stack_name
```

Comment: This reply should be the accepted one. The use of the `docker-compose config` and the use of the pipe make the call to `docker stack deploy` a real pleasure!

Comment: Just in case someone is facing the 'unsupported Compose file version: 1.0' i had when using this command : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69607819/7098666