# Unsupported Compose file version: 1.0 , even when I have the right compatability settings

Tags: docker

I am trying to stack deploy.

```
> docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml name
unsupported Compose file version: 1.0
```

These are my settings

```
> docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.6.0, build d99cad6
docker-py version: 1.7.0
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014


> docker version
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.0-beta3
```

I meet the compatibility requirements, specified here https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.6.0

> Note that Compose 1.6.0 requires Docker Engine 1.9.1 or later, or
>   1.10.0 if you're using version 2 of the Compose File format (see the changelog below).

Why isn't this working?

Comment: did you add the version header to your `docker-compose.yml` file ?

Comment: @LinPy according to docs `Version 1, the legacy format. This is specified by omitting a version key at the root of the YAML.` So I should be fine right

Comment: yes you are right, I read your question wrongly first time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I encountered this error while using a command to preprocess docker-compose.yml file in order to use variable interpolation with `docker stack deploy` command.

**Command :**
`docker compose -f docker-compose.swarm.yml config | docker stack deploy --compose-file - stackname`

**Error :**
`unsupported Compose file version: 1.0`

This is caused by `docker compose -f docker-compose.swarm.yml config` command not outputing the "version: '3.8'" line from my docker-compose file for some reasons so it falls back to '1.0'

---

**Quick workaround :**
`(echo -e "version: '3.8'\n";  docker compose -f docker-compose.swarm.yml config) | docker stack deploy --compose-file - stackname`

Comment: I remembered that I had forgotten this so thanks for the reminder. However, I can't get this to work with compose v2 in docker which is really annoying.